# Fluid simulator not working in animation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I made a cup and some liquid inside the cup using fluid simulator. The cup is animated thus moving. However the liquid would leak out the cup and would be spilled on the floor. The cup is the effector and the liquid is the flow. The liquid is shaped like a cup with a ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fanm2P5ITCs) very helpful.